# How to obtain explicit formula of coefficients for generating functions

Tags: sage, coefficients, power-series

Is there any function in python or sage to obtain explicit formula of coefficients for generating functions.
For example, Catalan generating function is given as

`$${\displaystyle c(x)={\frac {1-{\sqrt {1-4x}}}{2x}}}$$`

And I need to obtain general formula for nth coefficient:

`$${\displaystyle C_{n}={\frac {1}{2n+1}}{2n+1 \choose n}\,,}$$`